# Book Title vs Book Name!

Tags: word-choice, difference

Is it the "title of the books" or the "name of the book"? which one should I use and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A book generally has two things on the cover - a title, and a name. The name belongs to the author who wrote it, so don't call the title a 'name', just say title, otherwise it could be confusing.